# android LinkedList iterator , how to skip iteration

Tags: android, iterator

currently this is working fine for iteration
        Iterator iterator = android.iterator();

```
    //Using Iterator to iterate over List
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String version = iterator.next();
        int versionIndex = android.indexOf(version);
        System.out.println(version, versionIndex);  // I get v1, index[0]... 
    }
```

but , for testing purpose , I want to bypass the first element and skip to the 2nd only..

```
   while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String version = iterator.next();
        int versionIndex = android.indexOf(version);
        if (versionIndex == 0) {
           version = iterator.next()
           versionIndex = android.indexOf(version);
        }
        System.out.println(version, versionIndex);  // should start with v2, index[1]
    }
```

but it doesn't change the version ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call iterator.next() once before you start your while loop. This will advance the Iterator to the second position. Make sure you check for null.

Comment: yes, that's it...  and the issue is actually null elements...   I initialized a LinkedList  ( so null elements ) and I want to skip the first null element...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
if(iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String version = iterator.next();
        int versionIndex = android.indexOf(version);        
        System.out.println(version, versionIndex); 
    }
```